# QPainter draw numbers on clock

Tags: qt, c++11

```
QPainter graduation(this);
pen.setWidth(2);
pen.setColor(Qt::white);
graduation.setPen(pen);
graduation.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
graduation.translate(center.x(), center.y());
double newRadius = (width() - 50) / 2;
//qreal angleStep = 270 / m_stepsize;
for (int i = 0; i <= m_stepsize; i++)
{
    graduation.save();
    graduation.rotate(i * angleStep + 135);
    graduation.drawLine(newRadius - 8, 0, newRadius, 0);
    graduation.drawText(newRadius - 30, 0, "100");
    graduation.restore();
}
```

I used code above to draw numbers on clock. Here is what i get 
[image]

But i want to draw numbers to look like the image below. It must not be upside down.
[image]

Can anyone help me. I understand about rotate function that's is the reason its happen to the numbers, but i can not figure it out how to fix it.

Comment: Do not use drawText in the graduation.rotate() context, but calculate the positions manually and draw the text there.

Comment: Calculate the position manually that way is much more difficult and way too long.

Comment: It would be interesting if you post your solution (it is fine to answer your own question).

Comment: My solution can fix the problem "upside down" but it can not draw exactly like the clock i have shown. It just look like this : http://www.aeternusconsulting.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/dashboard-gauge-are-useless.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the position manually and draw the text unrotated:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= m_stepsize; i++)
{
    graduation.save();
    graduation.rotate(i * angleStep + 135);
    graduation.drawLine(newRadius - 8, 0, newRadius, 0);
    graduation.restore();
    double xpos=(newRadius - 30)*cos((i * angleStep + 135.)/360.*2.*3.14159);
    double ypos=(newRadius - 30)*sin((i * angleStep + 135.)/360.*2.*3.14159);
    graduation.drawText(xpos, ypos, "100");
}
```

Comment: @user2652023 Can you try it again. There was a factor 2 missing.

Comment: Greate. Its work. Many thanks to you. Even though it still have to config a little bit to draw more exactly. But i can not do it without ur idea. Once again i may need to ask you something. I understand the calculate "(newRadius - 30)*cos((i * angleStep + 135.)/360.*2.*3.14159)" but why do we have to divide by 360*2*3.14159

Comment: @user2652023 The builtin `cos` and `sin` works with angles in radian (0..2*pi) not in degrees (0..360), this is the reason why the angles need to be converted. PS: Please accept my answer if it worked such that other user can see that your problem is solved.

Comment: I get it now, thanks you so much. I'm new to stackoverflow. So i just knew the button "accept", I have already did it. Sorry for this missing.